# Downgrade PHP version 5.5.9 to 5.3.8

Tags: 14.04, php, downgrade

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I wish to downgrade PHP version 5.5.9 to 5.3.8 but I'm stuck because I can't find a tutorial for exactly this.

Comment: No, you don't want to do that.